# Indy SMTP hangs or freezes up on Connect method

Tags: delphi, smtp, c++builder, indy

I have a client attempting to connect SMTP server. I have the OnStatus event linked to the smtp client and see the

Resolving / Connecting / Connected states.  But sometimes there is a hangup / application freezes when trying to connect.  I see the Connected state being raised from OnStatus though.  What could the issue be.  I ruled out the Resolving DNS ans et both ConnectTimeout and Readtimeout settings on smtp as shown here:

```
  smtp.OnStatus := SMTPStatus;
  smtp.ConnectTimeout := 10000;
  smtp.ReadTimeout := 10000;
  smtp.Connect;
  // SOMETIMES MY LOG DOES NOT GET HERE Log('AfterConnect');
  if smtp.Connected then
  begin
    smtp.Send(Mess);
    smtp.Disconnect;
  end
```

On about 600KB attachment it seems to be getting stuck on encoding the attachment part and never completes, currently the encoding type is the default one.

```
10/3/2012 10:21:43 AM  Status: Resolving hostname XXXXXXXXXX.com.
10/3/2012 10:21:43 AM  Status: Connecting to 10.5.2.171.
10/3/2012 10:21:44 AM  Status: Connected.
10/3/2012 10:21:45 AM  Status: Encoding text
10/3/2012 10:21:45 AM  Status: Encoding attachment
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `OnStatus` event is reporting `hsConnected` then you are physically connected to the server.  If `Connect()` is not exiting afterwards then it is likely blocked waiting for data from the server that is not arriving, such as the server's initial Greeting.  The `ReadTimeout` should be handling that possibility, though (unless you have an `OnConnected` event handler assigned that is becoming deadlocked, that is).  Use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to make sure that you are actually connecting to the server you are expecting and that it is sending the right kind of greeting data that `TIdSMTP` is expecting.

Comment: Yes, whenever you have network communication problems, you should always sniff packets to rule out comm errors before then tracking down coding errors.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `Connect()` freezing up. That is a completely separate issue. Indy encodes emails dynamically as they are being transmitted. So either Indy has became deadlocked while reading the attachment data, Indy has a bug that crashed/deadlocked the encoding process, or the SMTP server has stopped receiving data on its end so Indy's socket gets blocked when the outgoing buffer fills up.

Comment: So what would be the work around for this case, will it make sense to have a timer inside a thread that frees the smtp client causing a forceful termination?

Comment: No, you need to track down what is actually freezing up during the sending/encoding and fix it (or, if it is a bug inside of Indy, let me know so I can fix it). You can compile Indy for debugging and then step through its source code in the debugger.

Comment: I can probably put logging in Indy code, do you know what areas of the code could be the potential for such a freeze?  We use D2007 with Indy 10

Comment: This is too broad an area to pinpoint spots of interest for you. That is why I suggest you actually step through the code. There is a lot of code involved when encoding an email. Do you have the same freezing if you use one of the `TIdMessage.SaveTo...()` methods instead of the `TIdSMTP.Send()` method? Or is this strictly an SMTP-only freeze?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I was under impression that IdSmtp control does create a Thread but after debugging I don't see a thread being created.  Did I miss something or is it the fact that there is currently no additional thread being created when using TIdSmtp?

Comment: No, `TIdSMTP` does not create an additional thread. Like most other Indy clients, it runs in the context of the thread that is using it. The only Indy clients that create new threads for their internal work are `TIdTelnet`, `TIdCmdTCPClient`, and `TIdIPMCastClient`.

Answer (score 1):

Many SMTP server are configured to delay the initial greeting msg by 30 or so seconds to try and deter SPAM, Also most servers can be configured to reject connections from the same ip addresses if it has tried to connect multiple times within a specified time period (typically 1 Min). It could be this that is causing you issues.

Comment: If that were the case, `TIdSMTP` would not be reaching the encoding stage, as shown in Dmitry's log. `TIdSMTP` has to validate the server's greeting before it can do anything else.

Comment: @Remy I added this answer a long time ago before the question was edited to include the log and more information. It was my best guess based on the available information.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice the timestamp.